# How to download a File in FIFO order From FTP server

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I have written window service, which will download single file from ftp server, now I want to download file in fifo order, i.e. First Download file which upload first.

```
                    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        List<string> result = ReadFileList(response.GetResponseStream());

                    private List<string> ReadFileList(Stream stream)
            {
         List<string> list = new List<string>();
         StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
         while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            list.Add(sr.ReadLine());
         sr.Close();
         stream.Close();

         return list;
            }
```

i have done code for connecting with ftp,response.GetResponseStream() return all files from ftp server,**i want to download single file which was first uploaded** from list of file.

Comment: What language have you written that service in? What have you tried? Any specific problems with what you're trying?

Comment: i have written in c# .net and problem when i call method              FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            List<string> result = response.GetResponseStream());      it return me all file from ftp server i want one file which was first uploded...

Comment: Then please write this in the question. You can still edit it. Along with a more details about what problem you actually have with that method call...